# Path Param giving null value when combined with POST method

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am trying to create a Restful Webservices for POST method.

I am trying to pass two variables as path params and get the JSON input from request body.

my code will look like below.

---

```
@POST

@Path("/{applicationNum}/{emailId}/example")

@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public ResponseVO testMethod(@PathParam("applicationNum") String applicationNum,@PathParam("emailID") String emailID,String jsonString);
```

---

The URL that i am using

```
/services/1111/adar@test.com/example
```

where 1111 is the application number and adar@test.com is the email id. I will get the value for `jsonString` from request body since this is a POST call.

On printing the output. I am able to get the application number but the email id is coming as null.

Please help me out to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

EmailID and EmailId is different (uppercase and lowercase D).  Change one of them and this should fix it.

Comment: The difference exists in the Path component.  The "emailID" in the PathParam and 'emailId' in the Path component are different.  These must match.

Comment: @user3736522 see the case of emailID and  emailId (D vs d)

Comment: The difference exists between the emailId in the line "/{applicationNum}/{emailId}/example" (line 3), and the "emailID" (the one enclosed in quotes) in line 8.  These must match.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code:

```
@Path("/{applicationNum}/{emailId}/example")

@PathParam("emailID") String emailID
```

your path parameter name is `emailId` and you are accessing it using `emailID` (please spot the capitalization). So, you are getting `null`.

**Solution**
Either change your code to: `@PathParam("emailId") String emailID`,
or turn your path into: `@Path("/{applicationNum}/{emailId}/example")`.

Both will work.